# WPF operation after filling camps

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm quite new to c#, especially for application with an interface. I looked for example or guide on `WPF` but they are too simple. Here is what I would to do:

1) a button to browse on directory and select files;

2) a `Listbox` and a `textBox` will be filled using info by the filenames selected previously;

3) rename those files by web info only when `Listbox` and `textbox` are filled.

Point 1) and 2) are done: I wrote the necessary code inside click button event. I was thinking to write code for point 3) inside `MainWindow` but those lines of code are carried out before I can select files, then there isn't any data yet.

The easy solution could be to insert the rest of the code inside the click button event too, but I think it's horrible. At the moment I can't understand what to write in the MAIN on a `WPF` app.
The code is:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void webLink_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://www.battlecraft.it/");
    }

    private void loader_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
        ofd.Multiselect = true;
        ofd.ShowDialog();
        listBox1.Items.Clear();
        string[] files = ofd.FileNames;
        string[] filenames = new string[files.Length];
        for (int i=0; i<files.Length; i++)
        {
            filenames[i] = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(files[i]);
            listBox1.Items.Add(filenames[i]);
        }
        if (listBox1.Items.Count != 0)
        {
            string SeEp = Regex.Match(filenames[0], @"\d+\w\d+").Value;
            string[] str = Regex.Split(filenames[0], @"\d\d\w+\d\d");
            string titolo = str[0].Replace(".", " ");

            MatchCollection m = Regex.Matches(SeEp, @"\d\d");
            titleBox.Text = titolo;
            seasonBox.Text = "stagione " + m[0].Value;
            int episode = int.Parse(m[1].Value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This would be quite a bit cleaner if you utilized the MVVM pattern and encapsulated out certain functionality (like the file selection).

Answer (score 0):

I've just learnt the concept of Binding and this should solve my problem. Binding the IsEnabled property of the startBtn to the Length of listbox1 and listbox2 should disable the button when they are empty and enable it otherwise.

I created a simple bind only between startBtn and listbox1 like following:

```
<Button x:Name="startBtn" Content="Rinomina" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="255,79,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Height="36" IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=listBox1, Path=Text.Length}"/>
```

and it works without adding any line of code in c#. I should use MultiBinding but I can't understand the syntax to pass 2 textboxes. Is it also possible without write any code in c#?